# AngularJS, interface not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an unordered list and when clicking on each `ListItem` it calls `setActive()`

```
<li ng-repeat="slide in data" ng-click="setActive(slide.slideIndex)">
  <span class="listItemText">
    <b>{{slide.slideIndex + 1}}. </b>{{slide.Title}}
  </span>
</li>
```

`setActive()` is:

```
$scope.setActive = function(id)
{
    $scope.currentIndex = id;
}
```

When I click on the `List Items` I update an image:

`<img id="slide" ng-src="resources/slides/slide{{currentIndex + 1}}.jpg" />`

**That all works fine**

What isn't working is I have a video player that at certain `time`s I need to update `$scope.currentIndex`

I thought this would work fine:

```
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function()
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key)
    {
        if (currentTime >= $scope.data[key].time && currentTime <= $scope.data[key].time + 0.3 && $scope.currentIndex != key)
        {
            console.log("load id:" + key);
            $scope.setActive(key); //Calling what works when I click a listItem
        }
    });
});
```

The `console.log` works and logs at the cue points, however, the image doesn't update until I `MouseOver` the list. At that point, the image will update to whatever `$scope.currentIndex` happens to be. I am totally lost on this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are updating your model outside of the typical Angular execution context, you need to use scope.$apply() so that Angular knows that it needs to run $digest and potentially update the view. See more about $apply here:

[$rootScope.Scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

Basically, if you wrap your call to setActive in $apply, then Angular will know that it needs to update the view. This should do the trick:

```
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function()
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key)
    {
        if (currentTime >= $scope.data[key].time && currentTime <= $scope.data[key].time + 0.3 && $scope.currentIndex != key)
        {
            console.log("load id:" + key);

            // Wrap the call in $apply so Angular knows to call $digest
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.setActive(key);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: awesome! That did the trick, thank you! I read something on apply earlier and wasn't able to get it to work. I was close at least..thanks again